# File permission numerical value of "rws"

Tags: permissions

I know `rwx` = 7 in absolute permissions or numerical/octal representation of the permissions.

But what number is used to represent permission `rws`? (where the s is the set-uid bit that tells execution to happen with the privileges of the file owner).

For example: `rwxrwsr--`

I have never heard of anything higher that 777 so perhaps is there not a numerical representation for this?

Additionally, is it possible to have the set-uid bit in both user and group (ex. `rwsrwsr--`)? And if so what would be the numerical representation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special modes can be set numerically (octal) with a prefix like this:

> The setuid bit is set with 4000 e.g: "chmod 4755 file".

> The setgid bit is set with 2000 e.g: "chmod 2755 file".

> The sticky bit is set with 1000 e.g: "chmod 1755 file".

So setting a setuid bit only on a file with "777" permissions is done like this:

```
chmod 4777 file
```

Reference: [Permissions Calculator](http://permissions-calculator.org/info/).

Comment: That permission calculator is super helpful thank you!

Comment: Regarding your example, either the text should have setuid instead of sticky, or it should be 1777 for 4777, right?

Comment: You're right, corrected!

Answer (score 5):

Octal permissions actually have 4 digits.

`777` is just a short version for `0777`, where the first digit is for `setuid` (4) and `setgid` (2).

```
chmod 6777
```

will set `setgid` + `setuid` (4+2=6)

See also:

- [What is the first chmod octal digit in a four-digit value for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6905/what-is-the-first-chmod-octal-digit-in-a-four-digit-value-for)

Comment: Thank you! Super helpful. I hadn't realized the first octal bit was used in this way. So to confirm `rwxrwsr-t` would then have a 5 in the first digit as setuid and sticky bit?

Comment: @JFreeman It would be `3775` since the `s` comes at group's place (=2).